# Emulator Temp files eating up my disk

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator

I found that my android emulator is creating temp files nearly a 1 Gb each inside C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator. So the emulator is not starting due to limited space.

What are these temp files?
Are these temp files important enough to keep it?
Can i delete it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Look at

```
c:\Users\<your_username>\.android\avd\
```

I think that safe way to clean is using Wipe option at AVD Manager.
Usually each emulator takes about 1 Gb on the disk.

Comment: @llya I have done that. but that didn't solve my problem. The temp files inside AndroidEmulator weigh up about 25GB approx.

Answer (score 0):

If the emulator isn't running, you can safely delete the files in `AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator`.

Also, if huge temporary files are still being produced in this location, consider upgrading the emulator. I can't identify exactly which version fixed this, but on my machine the files stopped appearing some time in 2016, despite me having created many AVDs since then.